# How to open/edit documents stored in SharePoint from wpf/remote application?

Tags: wpf, sharepoint, ms-office

I have below mentioned approach to open/edit the documents which are stored in SharePoint, but none of these approaches gives an option to pass authentication token if I have, so that SharePoint does not prompt for credentials to log in.

1. Using process start method

   ```
   system.Diagnostics.Process.Start(documentUrl);
   ```

   Using this potion document always gets opened in read-only mode.
   If i create ProcessStartInfo object with username and domain and password properties set        and pass this object to Process.Start method it always fails with exception saying file not found
2. Using interop assemblies

   ```
   Document Doc = wordApplication.Documents.Open()
   ```

   In this case document save and update to SharePoint needs to be handled explicitly.
   No way to pass authentication token
3. Using open document activex control of office

   ```
   Type t = null;
   t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.1"); 
   if (t == null) 
   { 
      Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2"); 
   } 
   if (t == null) 
   { 
     t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3"); 
   } 

   Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t); 
   object[] parms = { documentUrl, string.Empty }; 
   t.InvokeMember("EditDocument", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, null, o, openParms);
   ```

   This approach does not have a way to pass authentication information.

Any useful info or pointers to solve this will be very helpful.